# FileWebRequest Acces Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the program I developed with .Net Core, I want to send a file to a remote server (file server). When I send from local, there is no problem, but when sending a file in live, I get the error access to the path is denied. The error persists even though I have logged in, how can I solve it?

Comment: We cant debug a story. How are you accessing this file. Show the line of code. Do you have the right permissions set. Also please read [ask]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, to be able to help you we'll need more information, specifically a [mcve], in short: Your code that's failing (you can use "example.org" instead if the actual url/ ip of the remote server)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do you send files to the server in real time? Can you provide some detailed code examples?